# XML::LibXML findnodes() does not return results when xmlns is present

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I'm using XML::LibXML::Reader to parse a large document and have run into an issue whereby the attribute xmlns causes findnodes() to fail. I fixed it by added a regex to remove the xmls attribute but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution involving no regexes. If you remove the regex line ($xml =~ s{xmlns...) you'll see that say "Loc = $loc" produces no results.

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use XML::LibXML::Reader qw( XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT );

my $xml = <<'__EOI__';
<url xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <loc>http://example.com</loc>
    <lastmod>2018-10-19</lastmod>
</url>
__EOI__


$xml =~ s{xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"}{};

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( string => $xml);
while ( $reader->read ) {
    next unless $reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT;
    next unless $reader->name eq 'url';
    my $xml = $reader->readOuterXml;
    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);
    say "Doc = $doc";
    my ($loc) = $doc->findnodes('//loc');
    say "Loc = $loc";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You ask to find nodes with namespace null and with name `loc`. There are no such nodes in the document, so `findnodes` correctly returns nothing.

You want to find the nodes with namespace `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` and with name `loc`. You can use the following to achieve that:

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs( sm => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' );

my ($loc) = $xpc->findnodes('//sm:loc', $doc);
```

Comment: Note: Older versions of XML::LibXML requires that you explicitly load XML::LibXML::XPathContext.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. I must admit I was completely unaware of needing to use namespaces with docs that have them so I appreciate the new window on XML processing that you've opened for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your code starts by using the `XML::LibXML::Reader` API and then later uses `XML::LibXML->load_xml` to create a DOM from part of the document.  The `XML::LibXML::Reader` API is usually only used with huge XML documents that would consume large amounts of memory when loaded as a DOM.  If your XML document is not huge, then it's much simpler to use an approach like [ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52906138/293652) which just uses the DOM API to load the whole document and then query it with XPath.

However, if you really do have a huge XML document then you might be interested in solving the problem using the Reader API:

```
my $sitemap_uri = 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9';
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs(sm => $sitemap_uri);

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => './sitemap.xml');
while ($reader->read) {
    $reader->nextElement('url', $sitemap_uri) or last;
    my $doc = $reader->copyCurrentNode(1);
    say "Doc = $doc";
    my ($loc) = $xpc->findnodes('//sm:loc', $doc);
    say "Loc = $loc";
}
```

The call to `$reader->nextElement` is a quick way to skip forward to the next occurrence of a particular element.  In this example I matched on both the element name and it's namespace.

The call to `$reader->copyCurrentNode(1)` is a convenience method that returns that node and all it's child nodes as a DOM fragment.  You'll need to use `XML::LibXML::XPathContext` to query that DOM using namespace-aware XPath statements.

My XML::LibXML tutorial includes coverage of [working with XML namespaces](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/namespaces.html) as well as [working with large documents](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/large-docs.html).

Comment: I used your site quite a lot when learning about Perl XML processing and can't believe I've not seen the working with XML namespaces page before! Many thanks for the great work you're doing.