# Perl remove duplicate XML tags

Tags: xml, perl, command-line, duplicates

I have the following XML file:

```xml
<d:entry id="a" d:title="a">
  <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
  <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
  <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
  <d:index d:value="c" d:title="c"/>
  <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
  <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
  <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
  <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
</d:entry>
<d:entry id="b" d:title="b">
  <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
  <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
  <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
</d:entry>
```

(Whitespace added for readability.)

There are some duplicates of `<d:index`, I need to get rid of all the duplicates and only keep one unique `<d:index`. The desired effect is like this:

```xml
<d:entry id="a" d:title="a">
   <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
   <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
   <d:index d:value="c" d:title="c"/>
   <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
</d:entry>
<d:entry id="b" d:title="b">
  <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
  <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
  <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
</d:entry>
```

I can do the regex replacement in some editors for that purpose, but it needs to be done multiple times, I was wondering if Perl has some ways to do this in one run.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Catmandu::Fix can probably do it, but I don't know how off-hand.  Sorry about that!

Comment: This looks very interesting. After browsing for a while, I didn't find the right util method to remove the duplicate index, though.

Comment: What parser are you using? What's your code so far?

Comment: I didn't use any parser. I thought just perl + regex will do… Sorry, but I'm still new to Perl and not familiar with some libs in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a common way to filter out duplicates:

```
my @filtered = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @unfiltered;
```

This can be adapted to your needs, as shown in the following snippet:

```
my %seen;
for my $index_node ($xpc->findnodes('d:index', $entry_node)) {
   my $value = $xpc->findvalue('@d:value', $index_node);
   my $title = $xpc->findvalue('@d:title', $index_node);
   if ($seen{$value}{$title}++) {
      $index_node->unbind();
   }
}
```

(I used my preferred parser, XML::LibXML, since you didn't mention which parser you were using.)

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for your answer. Is this possible to write in Perl oneliner? :)

Comment: I don't know of any existing tool, no. Furthermore, requests for tool suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: After I import the `XML::LibXML`, and try to run the snippet above, it gives the error,  `Global symbol "$xpc" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $xpc"?) at 1.pl line 7.
Global symbol "$entry_node" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $entry_node"?) at 1.pl line 7.` I don't know if I missed some module to import, or should I declare the $xpc.

Comment: You will need an XML::LibXML::XPathContext object in order to define `d`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52906138/589924)

Comment: I see, thanks @ikegami. That's really helpful to know.:)  Another confusion is how do we get the `$entry_node`. Is there another `for loop` on the outside of the current `for loop` to get each `$entry_node`?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who knows anything about XML will tell you not to do this using regex processing, but using a proper XML parser and XML tools. It can probably be done using regular expressions (though not by me) if you know that the format of the file will always be exactly as you have shown it, e.g. with the newlines and double quotes and attribute order exactly as in your example. But if you put this into production, then someone generating the XML is going to ask on StackOverflow in a years' time how to ensure that they can generate XML in precisely this format because the receiving application breaks if the attributes are in the wrong order or use single quotes rather than double quotes. So you're creating problems for the future. (Remember Postel's law, which in this case means that you should accept any well-formed XML that is equivalent to this XML).

In any case, it's so much easier to do this in XSLT than the way you are proposing. Assuming you want both attributes to match for the element to count as a duplicate, then the code is:

```
<xsl:template match="d:entry">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="d:index" 
                      group-by="concat(@d:value, '~', @d:title)">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
  <xsl:copy-of select="div"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

By the way, you said "whitespace added for readability". That whitespace, especially if it includes newlines, is going to have a major effect on any regex solution, but no effect at all on properly-written XSLT.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Key I was learning this `XSLT` approach, while it gives the following error: `compilation error: file remove_duplicate_indices.xsl element for-each-group
xsltStylePreCompute: unknown xsl:for-each-group`. I'm using `XML::LibXSLT ` to do it.

Comment: I changed the xsl file a bit, and it's not throwing the error anymore. But the result is not expected; It deletes all the `<d:index`, and only leaves with two `div` contents without `<div` as the tag.

Comment: Just posted a new post regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56919764/1118630

Comment: I should have mentioned that to use xsl:for-each-group you need an XSLT 2.0 processor. XSLT 2.0 came out 12 years ago, but sadly some processors, like LibXSLT, were never updated.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay. I tried to install a `XSLT` 2.0 processor of `Perl`, but with no success. I think I'll try `XSLT` approach later.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
perl -MMojo::DOM -0777 -E'my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse(<>);
  $dom->find(q{d\\:entry})->each(sub { my %seen;
    $_->find(q{d\\:index})->each(sub {
      $_->remove if $seen{$_->{"d:value"}}{$_->{"d:title"}}++ }) });
  print $dom->to_string' input.xml
```

Results in:

```
<d:entry d:title="a" id="a">
  <d:index d:title="a" d:value="a" />
  <d:index d:title="b" d:value="b" />

  <d:index d:title="c" d:value="c" />



  <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
</d:entry>
<d:entry d:title="b" id="b">
  <d:index d:title="a" d:value="a" />
  <d:index d:title="b" d:value="b" />
  <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
</d:entry>
```

- If the actual content doesn't have such whitespace, it won't be left over after removing the tags. Otherwise a little more logic can remove the whitespace text nodes.
- I would use [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo) for this but it doesn't have a shortcut for XML-mode parsing.
- If the XML contains any non-ascii characters you will need to decode it on STDIN and encode it on STDOUT according to its encoding; if it's the usual UTF-8, you can use the `-CS` switch to do this.

Comment: I just realized this is to remove duplicate `<d:index` globally. What if it needs to be in a `<d:entry` scope. i.e. Different entries can actually have the same `<d:index`, and in this case, the global duplicate `<d:index` doesn't count as duplicate in the scope of one `<d:entry`.

Comment: I tried this, but it gave an error: `perl -MMojo::DOM -0777 -E'my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse(<>);
$dom->find(q{d\\:entry})->each(my %seen, $_->find(q{d\\:index})->each(sub { $_->remove if $seen{$_->{"d:value"}}{$_->{"d:title"}}++ }));
print $dom->to_string;' input.xml` - error message: `Can't call method "find" on an undefined value`

Comment: @jonah_w That is not an appropriate way to call `each`. Try my updated version.

Comment: Whoa, that's how Mojo::DOM handles namespaces? ouch! One should never have to depend on knowing the prefix (or lack thereof) that will be used. One should have to know the namespace.

Comment: @ikegami It is just one option. You can also pass namespace aliases to [find](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#find), but that seems out of scope for a one liner and such information is not provided in the OP.

Comment: You could have used `my $ns = '...';` and let the OP fill in the `...` instead of introducing 4 bugs.