# Remove duplicate XML elements using XSLT with perl XML::LibXSLT

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I have this XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:dictionary xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng">
    <d:entry id="a" d:title="a">
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="c" d:title="c"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
    </d:entry>
    <d:entry id="b" d:title="b">
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
    </d:entry>
</d:dictionary>
```

I'm trying to remove the duplicate `<d:index` of the entries using `XSLT` following this posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56898207/589924

> Note: Every entry have its own independent `<d:index`, i.e. same index
>   in different entries should not count as a duplicate. And the resulting xml should honor the original xml format.

The `xsl` file is like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng">
<xsl:template>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="d:index"
                            group-by="concat(@d:value, '~', @d:title)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:copy-of select="div"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result is not expected, it removes all tags except for the content of `div`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>









This is the content for entry.




This is the content for entry.
```

Comment: `xsl:for-each-group` requires XSLT 2.0. LibXSLT is an XSLT 1.0 processor. Use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) or   [EXSLT set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html).

Comment: P.S. A template **must** have a `match` or a `name` attribute (or both).

Comment: Just tried to install `XML::Saxon::XSLT2` for `XSLT` 2.0 support, but failed… Why `Perl `libraries are so hard to install… :(

Comment: Blame goes to your less than awesome OS X package manager. Installing the dist with XML::Saxon::XSLT2 took me less than a minute on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using the [Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng" exclude-result-prefixes="d">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kIndexByValueTitle" match="d:index"
          use="concat(generate-id(..), '+', @d:value, '+', @d:title)"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
   "d:index[not(generate-id()
               = generate-id(key('kIndexByValueTitle',
                                  concat(generate-id(..), '+', @d:value, '+', @d:title)
                                 )
                                  [1]))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied against the provided XML document**:

```
<d:dictionary xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng">
    <d:entry id="a" d:title="a">
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="c" d:title="c"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
    </d:entry>
    <d:entry id="b" d:title="b">
        <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
        <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
        <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
    </d:entry>
</d:dictionary>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<d:dictionary xmlns:d="http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <d:entry id="a" d:title="a">
      <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
      <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
      <d:index d:value="c" d:title="c"/>
      <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
   </d:entry>
   <d:entry id="b" d:title="b">
      <d:index d:value="a" d:title="a"/>
      <d:index d:value="b" d:title="b"/>
      <div>This is the content for entry.</div>
   </d:entry>
</d:dictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Dimitre Novatchev I should have mentioned every entry have its own independent `<d:index`, i.e. same index in different entries should not count as a duplicate.

Comment: @jonah_w, Thanks -- you must provide in the question the wanted result.

I edited the answer and it now reflects your latest requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding @Dimitre Novatchev, I have just updated the question. So I tried your solution, it was awesome. One thing though, it seems like the xml is reformatted into two lines (lost its original format). I was wondering if it could keep the format while removing the duplicates?

Comment: @jonah_w, I don't know what you mean by "original format". The result from the transformation has the format of the XML document as provided in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I checked again. It was a mistake I made in the code. The resulting xml is perfect.:)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using directly programming libraries may be easier.
Following a Perl script using XML::DT

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::DT;
my $filename = shift;
my %seen=();

my %handler=(
    'd:entry' => sub{ %seen=(); toxml },                     ## reset seen
    'd:index' => sub{ if ($seen{$v{"d:value"}}++){""    }    ## $v{id} -- attribute id 
                      else                       {toxml}},
);
print dt($filename, %handler);
```

as usual, `sudo cpan XML::DT` if not installed.

Comment: Thanks @JJoao I just tried this approach. The resulting xml seems to have the xml declaration and namespace deleted.